# Install .IPA files from iOS app / cocoa

Tags: ios, cocoa, ssh, jailbreak, ipa

I'm creating an app for ios that works like Installous (this project is a private version for company users)
I've found InstallBash.sh from Installous folder and I tried it from SSH. It installs .ipa files but I have 2 problems:

1. The icon is not showing on the spring board, and ReSpring is not a solution for me (because it interupts the app actions). How can I make it work?
2. How can I execute the shell script from my iOS app?

P.S: yes this app is being created to be used on jailbroken iDevices, and the app itself will be installed from Cydia.

Can anyone help me on this?
Thank you

Comment: Finally a question that makes sense and is written in proper English. +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run a shell script from within your app, use the C standard library function `system()`:

```
system("/Applications/MyApp.app/installApp.sh someapp.ipa");
```

To show the app icon, you can have Saurik's UIKit Tools package as a dependency of your app and run - as user mobile - the uicache command:

```
system("uicache");
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much @H2CO3, I've read it but I didn't get what should I set in setuid(?) and setgid(?) to set user and group to mobile! :( would you help me with an example? sorry I'm new to this low level c functions.

Comment: @Shahin if you haven't used these functions at all, your app is already mobile. No more code needed :)

Comment: great thanks :D just I've checked the apps installed using my app, their "group" is "wheel" instead of "mobile". (other apps group is "mobile"), that's why I was thinking about changing group! should I change the group in my code?

Comment: @Shahin I am facing the same issue in my app, I have to download the ipa file form server and install it on device and I used github.com/kryhear/IPAInstaller, it worked fine for me but when I used the ipa that doesn't include my target device UDID's this code doesn't work, can you please put some light on the way that you used to accomplish the task?